# How to update unique properties of a User entity Google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying make the edit profile plate for a Google App Engine Boiler Plate

When a user edits the profile. The user entitiy whose model is

```
class User(User):
"""
Universal user model. Can be used with App Engine's default users API,
own auth or third party authentication methods (OpenId, OAuth etc).
based on https://gist.github.com/kylefinley
"""

#: Creation date.
created = model.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
#: Modification date.
updated = model.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
#: User defined unique name, also used as key_name.
username = model.StringProperty(required=True)
#: User Name
name = model.StringProperty()
#: User Last Name
last_name = model.StringProperty()
#: User email
email = model.StringProperty(required=True)
#: Password, only set for own authentication.
password = model.StringProperty(required=True)
#: User Country
country = model.StringProperty()

@classmethod
def get_by_email(cls, email):
    """Returns a user object based on an email.

    :param email:
        String representing the user email. Examples:

    :returns:
        A user object.
    """
    return cls.query(cls.email == email).get()
```

I obtained the user object by the code  for a particular user session

```
user_info = models.User.get_by_id(long(self.user_id))

#Made required changes to to user object such as country name lastname

#saved the entity

user_info.put()
```

Everything works fine. The User entitiy is updated.  But the unique entity is not .

My main question  how do i update them?

But when i see  Unique table in admin view

Image for unique table is  https://www.dropbox.com/s/sfbsn63023gsxil/unique.png

This table is not updated but this table is for entities is updated.

Image for user table is   https://www.dropbox.com/s/sfhw5l5ixdmlq7c/user.png

What should I do to update the unique properties  in the data store?

Comment: we will not be able to follow the links that you included, as we are not Administrators on your account, so a substantial part of your question is missing. You could either take some screen shots to include, but if you do so, please be careful to avoid including any information that might compromise the security of your application or your users. Alternatively, just describe in words what the problem is.

Comment: Hi, I shared the links to the two tables showing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to use the username as the key_name, but your implementation is confusing.

First, I don't see any code posted where you attempt to update a Unique entity.  In fact, there's no connection between your User entity and Unique entities.  If you want the Unique entity to update, you need to explicitly code it yourself.

On the bigger picture, I'm not sure why you need a unique entity at all.  What you probably want to do is use the username as the key_name when you create the User object.